# How do I loop a variable coming from the backend using ejs

Tags: javascript, html, ejs

The data coming from the backend is in this way:
`injector.camara1`
`injector.camara2`
`injector.camara3`
`injector.camara4`

I need to use them to show the value on inputs. I tried looping over the variables using something like this:

```
<% if(var i = 0; i < 4; i++) { %>
   <td>
     <input id="camara<%= i+1 %>" name="camara<%= i+1 %>" value="<%= injector.camara[i] %>">
   </td>
% } %>
```

But it isn't an array so it's not working. Is there anyway to work around this?

Comment: iterate over what you have: you have no idea what `i` should run to, so use `injector.camara.forEach`, which can't ever go wrong. See https://ejs.co and scroll to "Includes are relative to the template".

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, `injector` is an object that has several properties like `camera1`, `camera2`...

So, we need to loop over properties of an object. We can use `for... of` loops. The code looks like :

```
<% for(const [key, value] of Object.entries(injector)) { %>
   <td>
     <input id="<%= key %>" name="<%= key %>" value="<%= value %>">
   </td>
% } %>
```

You can see the document of `Object.entries` method [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/entries)